# Remove duplicate values from a multi-dimensional array and sum them

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

suppose I have an array like this :

```
   Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => A
            [1] => 20
        )

        [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => B
            [1] => 10
        )

        [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => G
            [1] => 5
        )

        [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => A
            [1] => 15
        )


    )
```

I would like to remove duplicate values and sum just a row of array :
What I want :

```
   Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => A
            [1] => 35 // <= sum : 20 + 15
        )

        [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => B
            [1] => 10
        )

        [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => G
            [1] => 5
        )



    )
```

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php) question before.

**updated**

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){

    $arr = array(
        'GoodMainCode'=>persian_sql_to_php($row['GoodMainCode']), // <= like A in the example
        'title'=> persian_sql_to_php($row['GoodName']),
        'author'=>persian_sql_to_php($row['moalef']),
        'publisher'=>persian_sql_to_php($row['Nasher']),
        'translator'=>persian_sql_to_php($row['Motarjem']),
        'price'=>persian_sql_to_php($row['SellPrice1']),
        'isbn'=>persian_sql_to_php($row['ISBN']),
        'amount'=>persian_sql_to_php($row['Amount']), // <= if GoodMainCode is same key, I must sum it.
        'year_of_publish'=>persian_sql_to_php($row['SaleChap']),
        'period_print'=>persian_sql_to_php($row['NobateChap'])
    );


    array_push($mjson,$arr);

}



//added

foreach($mjson as $v){

    if(!isset($result[$v['GoodMainCode']]))
        $result[$v['GoodMainCode']] = $v;
    else
        $result[$v['GoodMainCode']]['amount'] += $v['amount'];
}
```

Comment: How far did you get so far?

Comment: Show your code and where you don't get any further.

Comment: Post your attempts too..

Comment: I'm a newbie in php programming.

Comment: In this case you try to program the next possible solution: 1. Create empty destination array; Go thru the source array by foreach loop; For every element from source array check if is created the appropriate element in destination array. If created - simply increase it's value ( index 1) by value of checked source element. If not created - then create it - same as in source. In this way you'll got what you need. Is this make sense?

Comment: So where are we with this question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just loop through your array and check if in your `$result` array is a key with the letter of the current inner Array from `$arr`. If not add it to the `$result` array and initialize the second key with the number.

If there is already a key with this letter you can simply add the numbers together in this array. At the end I simply use `array_values()` to reindex the entire array.

```
<?php

    foreach($arr as $v) {
        if(!isset($result[$v[0]]))
            $result[$v[0]] = $v;
        else
            $result[$v[0]][1] += $v[1];
    }

    $result = array_values($result);
    print_r($result);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => A
            [1] => 35
        )
    //...
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => G
            [1] => 5
        )

)
```